# How to call this Controllers or Action?

Tags: sxa, sitecore-commerce

[image]

[image]

[image]

This action is not call in the browser!
How to call this Controllers or Action?

Comment: Do you have registered the `cxa` path? If yes try to rename to `CartHelperController` instead of `CartHelperControllers`. Instead od screenshots, better to post code as code snippet in a question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.this question cost one day of me.

Answer (score 2):

Did you register your route correctly?

From [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs):

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default",                                              // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

In Sitecore you want to register custom routes in the `Initialize` pipeline (from [Sitecore Docs](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/use-mvc-routing.html)):

> The safest and recommended way to add an MVC route is to add a
>   processor in the Initialize pipeline, register the routes, and
>   implement the route table in the RouteConfig class. This prevents you
>   from inadvertently breaking any Sitecore routes.

Also (from [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-controller-cs)):

> Every controller name must end with the suffix **Controller**. For
>   example, you can create a controller named ProductController but not a
>   controller named Product.

Looks like you named it `Controllers` instead of `Controller`